# Photoshop: how to save PDF at a particular file size?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf, image-quality, file-size

I want to save multiple files into a PDF presentation in Photoshop. When I save it at the high pdf setting the file is much too big. when I save it at the low quality option its too small and the quality falls significantly. Can I set a Photoshop PDF presentation to set too a particular file size in between eg. 10MB

Comment: Do not aim at a specific file size. Aim at a "Maximum" file size.

Answer (score 1):

You can't choose an exact size for the final PDF. What you can do is try different settings in the 'Compression' tab and see which ones will result in a file size close to your desired 10mb. Namely the 'Downsampling', 'Compression' and 'Image Quality' fields. Then save the settings as a preset so you can quickly re-use the same set of options for future exports.

[image]

Comment: Great. If you feel this answers your question try clicking the _check_ icon and/or the _up_ arrow next to my answer above. Thanks!